# Spring @ExceptionHandler test gets invoked but instead of error body it re-throws the Exception using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I am using Mockito to test Spring Exception Handler.

Here is the test Code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RestControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private InputValidationService inputValidationService;

    @InjectMocks
    private RestController controller;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private List<String> errors;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
                .setHandlerExceptionResolvers(withExceptionControllerAdvice())
                .setMessageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()).build();
    }

    private ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver withExceptionControllerAdvice() {
        final ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionResolver = new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver() {
            @Override
            protected ServletInvocableHandlerMethod getExceptionHandlerMethod(final HandlerMethod handlerMethod,
                                                                              final Exception exception) {
                Method method = new ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver(RestControllerAdvice.class).resolveMethod(exception);
                if (method != null) {
                    return new ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(new RestControllerAdvice(), method);
                }
                return super.getExceptionHandlerMethod(handlerMethod, exception);
            }
        };
        exceptionResolver.afterPropertiesSet();
        return exceptionResolver;
    }

    @Test
    public void thatExceptionHappens() throws Exception {

        Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = new HashSet<>();
        doThrow(new ConstraintViolationException(violations)).when(inputValidationService).validateInput(anyString());
        when(errorHelper.getErrorCode(anyString())).thenReturn("1000");        
        try {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/employee/details/9876")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().is(400));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("");
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the Controller Code:

```
@ControllerAdvice
    public class RestControllerAdvice {

        @Resource
        private ErrorHandler errorHandler;

        @ExceptionHandler(value = { ConstraintViolationException.class })
        @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
        @ResponseBody
        public ServiceError handleConstraintViolations(ConstraintViolationException e) {
            Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();
            return errorHandler.buildResponseFromViolations(violations);
        }
    }
```

When I run the test code, it throws the Exception and the execution goes to ControllerAdvice i.e. RestControllerAdvice (As expected)

(I checked that using Debugger)

Now here is the Issue:

The Exception handler i.e. handleConstraintViolations() composes the ErrorBody correctly but when the execution comes back to the test its actually an Exception instead of an ErrorBody

Here is the stack trace that might give you the idea of whats happening.

```
Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public ErrorBody RestControllerAdvice.handleConstraintViolations(javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException)
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:363)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:60)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(TestDispatcherServlet.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1022)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:170)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:141)
    at RestControllerTest.thatExceptionHappens(RestControllerTest.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
Could not complete request
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException
    at RestController.validateInput(RestController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:170)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:141)
    at RestControllerTest.thatExceptionHappens(RestControllerTest.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
```

So basically when the following line of code executes:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/employee/details/9876")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().is(400));
```

this particular line should not throw an exception, the exception and all should be taken care of ControllerAdvice and it should return the ErrorBody

Based on the answer below, here is some additional info that I found:

```
requestMediaTypes has the following "*/*"

supportedMediaTypes has the following

application/octet-stream
text/plain/;charset=ISO-8859
application/xml
text/xml
application/x-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-date
*/*

producibleMediaTypes has the following

application/json;charset=UTF-8


compatibleMediaTypes has the following:

application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

List of message Converters associated:

```
0 = {ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter@2624} 
1 = {StringHttpMessageConverter@2655} 
2 = {SourceHttpMessageConverter@2665} 
3 = {AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter@2666}
```

Now I can see that problem happens when 
messageConverter1.canWrite(returnValueClass, selectedMediaType) gets executed and none of them are able to convert I guess.

Even though I might have gotten closer to the issue, I am still clueless as to how to solve the problem. is there something that I need to add in the setUp method of my test class.

Answer (score 0):

The response you return from your exception handler must fit to the "Accept" header of the request. If not, you will get the described exception.
Spring also consideres some defaults there, if the 'Accept' header is not set.

I faced a similar problem some days ago and tried to configure spring to always use a fixed Content-Type (e.g. application/json) for the response, but it turned out to be too complicated.

Set a breakpoint at line 189 of

AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor#writeWithMessageConverters

There you will see requestedMediaTypes,producibleMediaTypes and compatibleMediaTypes. This should give you more information about whats actually the root of the problem.

**Edit**

There is no generic solution to this problem.
You need to investigate, why spring comes to the conclusion, that there is no acceptable media type.
So the best advice I can give, is to check the three variables at the breakpoint described above.

- requestedMediaTypes - the media types of the requests 'Accept' header, or a default, if the header was not set
- producibleMediaTypes - the media types, that the controller method can produce.
- compatibleMediaTypes - the media types of the above, that spring considers compatible

If the compatibleMediaTypes are not null or empty, the error might happen when spring tries to serialize your ServiceError. So check whether you have the right annotations there, getter/setter id needed....

If the compatibleMediaTypes are null, than you have really incompatible media types and you have to change that.

*** How I solved my problem ***

My controller threw this exception when a client requested a media type which was just misspelled or not supported by my controller and I tried to return a JSON error response.
In this situation it makes some sense, NOT to return a JSON response, because the client cannot accept it anyways. So I just return the HTTP status 400 (Bad Request) and no content at all.

Comment: I am glad you managed to solve your issue. But how did you exactly solve the issue. Because the Error body (My response) is also supposed to be returned in JSON Format. So what am I supposed to do here exactly.

Comment: Based on your answer which is pretty good I must say. I narrowed down the real point of exception re-throwing but I am still clueless as to how to fix this. I have added a message converter in my set up which is not even showing up in the list of messageconverters.